# How can i fix this error? string escape

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_real_escape_string()

this is the way i declare:

```
$imageName=mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['name']);
$tmp_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

I tried to find its extension on `php.ini` config, and I think it is already included, why is it? Because when I don't use escape string, I cant properly upload the image. Thank you in advance for anyone who helping me.

Comment: Which PHP version do you use?

Comment: You're probably using a `mysql_` connection, yet you're not passing db connection to that escaping function. There isn't enough code/information to provide a concrete solution.

Comment: you have an answer below, ask them since you may not be checking comments. Good luck

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to write `mysqli_real_escape_string` for images.

You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to Escapes special characters entered by user in a string (text type) format which is further used to save in SQL statement.

For image you can use various `FILES` function like. `is_uploaded_file` and `getimagesize`

Comment: actually they do need it IF they're intending to upload as binary in their db and that's unknown.

Comment: ok...then for to use mysqli_real_escape_string properly they have to write $imageName=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn,$_FILES['image']['name']);
$tmp_name=mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conn,$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); where $db_conn is the database connection parameter.

Comment: that person isn't responding to comments up there, so he'll have to deal with you.

Comment: gotta try this too